# Running TensorFlow 2 setup.py in Google Colab loads forever and then times out

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab and am experiencing an issue when installing packages with python/pip following [this TensorFlow guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_object_detection.ipynb). It loads forever then I get a timeout error when running the [TensorFlow 2 setup script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py).

So then I tried to open [their own notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_object_detection.ipynb#scrollTo=NwdsBdGhFanc), which results in the same error. It just loads forever then throws a timeout. It is this line that loads forever: `python -m pip install .`

I am new to TensorFlow and Google Colab so I'm not sure how to debug this properly. How do I install the TensorFlow Object Detection API on Google Colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a known issue [as seen here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10396).